# Show that $\ker F$ is trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A,B,$ and $C$ be multiplicative groups, let $f:A→B$ and $g:A→C$ be group homomorphisms such that $\ker f ∩ \ker g=\{1\}.$ Let $F:A→B×C$ be defined by $F(a)=(f(a),g(a))$. 
>   (a) Show that $\ker F$ is trivial. 
>   (b) Find a subgroup of $B × C$ that is isomorphic to $A$.

**My attempt:**
First, we can show that $F$ is also a group homomorphism:

$F(a_1a_2)=(f(a_1a_2),g(a_1a_2))=(f(a_1)f(a_2),g(a_1)g(a_2))$ (since $f:A→B$ and $g:A→C$ are group homomorphisms) $=(f(a_1),g(a_1))(f(a_2),g(a_2))$ (the operation on the direct product $B×C$ is component-wise) $=F(a_1)F(a_2)$.

Now, for part a) I tried to use the fact that the kernel of a group homomorphism $F$ is trivial if and only if $F$ is injective. So suppose $F(a_1)=F(a_2)$, then $$(f(a_1),g(a_1))=(f(a_2),g(a_2)) \iff \begin{cases} f(a_1)=f(a_2) \\ g(a_1)=g(a_2) \end{cases}.$$ But I don't think this is the correct way to prove it, I believe we need to use the fact that $\ker f ∩ \ker g=\{1\}$ somehow. $\ker f ∩ \ker g=\{1\}$ doesn't imply $\ker f=\ker g=\{1\}$ right?

As for part b) I am completely stuck and have no ideas whatsoever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ugh, no. Don’t try to prove $F$ is injective. In fact, proving the kernel is trivial is the **easy** way to prove $F$ is injective. Just try to figure out what elements map to the identity. If $F(a) = (1,1)$, then $(f(a),g(a))=(1,1)$, so....

Comment: (Trying to prove the kernel is trivial by showing $F$ is injective is overkill; because to prove $F$ is injective you must show, among other things, that if $F(a)=F(1)$ then $a=1$... which is already a proof that the kernel is trivial)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, so $()=1$ and $g()=1$. Since  $∩=\{1\},$ it follows that $ker F = \{1\}???$

Comment: In part (a) you showed that the kernel is trivial. In particular, that shows that $F$ is injective, so $F$ takes $A$ into $B\times C$ in a one-to-one fashion. Use this to do (b) (Hint: first isomorphism theorem).

Comment: @dxdydz: Exactly.

Comment: @Liam, Since $KerF=\{1\},$ by the fundamental homomorphism theorem $\frac{A}{ \{1\}} \cong F(A). \frac{A}{ \{1\}} \cong A,  F(A) \leq B\times C,$ hence $A \cong F(A)$???

Comment: @dxdydz Yup. In general, if $G_1$ injects into $G_2$, then $G_1$ is isomorphic to its image in $G_2$ by the reasoning you just gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be in $\textrm{Ker}(F)$. As the neutral element of $B \times C$ is $(1_B, 1_C)$, one has $(f(x), g(x)) = (1_B, 1_C)$. So,$x$ belongs to both $\textrm{Ker}(f)$ and $\textrm{Ker}(g)$. Thus, $x = 1_A$ and $\textrm{Ker}(F)$ is trivial because included in $\{  1_A \}$ (the reciprocal inclusion is obvious).

This fact is a characterisation of the injectivity of group homomorphisms. This is sufficient to claim that the kernel of $F$ is included in $\{  1_A \}$.

As $F$ is injective, $F(A)$ is isomorphic to $A$ and as $F$ is a group homomorphism, $F(A)$ is a subgroup of $B \times C$. So $F(A)$ is the subgroup you are looking for.